# PlaylistItems seems to be limited to 20 000 entires for uploads playlist. Is there any workaround?

Tags: youtube-data-api

It seems that somewhat recently uploads playlists were limited to 20 000 entries. Is there a way to get list of all videos uploaded by a channel?

For example channel UCFL1sCAksD6_7JIZwwHcwjQ has 57 849 videos when searching for it:

`https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jtbc+entertainment`.

But its uploads playlist has only 20 000 videos:

`https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUFL1sCAksD6_7JIZwwHcwjQ`.

When querying YouTube Data API through Python, after reaching page that has 20 000th entry, nextPageToken doesn't exist.

How can I find rest of the videos?

Answer (score 4):

You may try using repeatedly the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint queried with the following parameters:

- `channelId=UCFL1sCAksD6_7JIZwwHcwjQ`,
- `type=video`,
- `order=date`,
- `publishedBefore=...`,
- `maxResults=50`,

where `publishedBefore` is computed appropriately.

The initial `publishedBefore` is set to 1 second before the value of the [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#snippet.publishedAt) property of the (chronologically) last video you have obtained from [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) endpoint invoked with `playlistId=UUFL1sCAksD6_7JIZwwHcwjQ`.

Successive values of `publishedBefore` will be set, similarly, to 1 second before the value of the [`publishedAt`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#snippet.publishedAt) property of the (chronologically) last video of the previous call to `Search.list` endpoint.

One more remark: do note that -- even if the API will allow you to go beyond the 20000 limit using the algorithm above (I don't know if it will; you have to test that yourself) -- the cost of this procedure is quite high: each `Search.list` endpoint call has a [quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) of 100 units (expensive indeed).

Comment: Results from that endpoint don't include all matching videos. For example, searching  with publishedBefore= '2013-09-20T02:57:56Z' returns videos, with published dates from 2013-09-19 to 2013-08-24 but the result doesn't include video DkIo-wbRJz4, which has been published 2013-09-16, which fits the returned range.

Comment: Indeed that's one of peculiarities of `Search.list` endpoint: it is not precise at all, but has a very fuzzy behavior. I can confirm that from my own experience; but I have no knowledge of anything official (from Google or YouTube) that might confirm this observed behavior. From the perspective of an API user, unfortunately, `Search.list` is entirely opaque.

Comment: Even if `Search.list` is fuzzy, from your point of view, it may still worth using this endpoint for to obtain from the API as much video IDs as you can, beyond that 20000 limit.