# YouTube Data API v3: etag implementation broken for ChannelListResponse, PlaylistListResponse and PlaylistItemListResponse

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've raised the following issue on [Google's bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138008530) on July 23rd 2019 and never got an answer if this will be fixed in YouTube's data API v3.

The problem is, that the current etag implementation of the YouTube data API v3 doesn't work for ChannelListResponse, PlaylistListResponse and PlaylistItemListResponse as the etag changes on each request, even if the data behind the corresponding request didn't change. This makes it impossible to cache this data and reduce the amount of API reuqests. The linked stackoverflow answer explains that the reason of this behaviour could be that the API gives back the items in another order per request and therefore sets a new etag.

How to reproduce:

1. Click [this link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLpR68gbIfkKnP7m8D04V40al1t8rAxDT0&fields=etag&_h=3&) and check the etag
2. Click the link again (multiple times) and you'll see that the etag changes from time to time

This etag beaviour works correctly on the PlaylistItemListResponse.Item entity (which is actually a video) where the etag stays always the same as long as the data of the video didn't change. So there are obviously different implementations how etags are handled on the YouTube data API v3.

Any idea if there's a workaround or if this issue will be fixed one day?

Comment: The question whether these *etag* issues will be fixed or not can only be answered by Google itself. In my SO experience (say the last two years) I never came across SO users that acknowledge their employment by Google and/or assume answering to questions in Google's name.

Comment: Further in the past, names like [Ibrahim Ulukaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973552/ibrahim-ulukaya) and [Jeff Posnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385997/jeff-posnick) were constantly involved with questions pertaining to the tags [tag:youtube-api] and [tag:youtube-data-api] while assuming openly their position within YouTube/Google.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. Hopefully this will be fixed in v4. For Google this could be a big deal to reduce the amount of heavy API requests / load.

Comment: This is [my bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138008530) on the Google tracker. They say it's fixed but it's not. Easy reproducible.

Comment: Then, please insist adding a comment to that thread with a concrete example that reproduces the bug. (It happened to me that [my insistence upon getting a plain wrong response](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/157449526#comment4) from Google staff led to nothing; but it may well be different in your case.)

Comment: The example is still working and easily reproducible. I've already added a comment that it still doesn't work. I will wait 1-2 weeks and comment again. So I give them an opportunity to reply to my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer to the following question:

> Are there workarounds for the *well-known issues of the `etag` properties* of [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list), [`Playlists.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) and [`PlaylistItems.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) API endpoints?

**1. The `Channels.list` endpoint**

In case of `Channels.list`, the things are simple (yet not trivial), because this endpoint returns at most 50 [Channel resources](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource). (Usually only one, but when one is setting the value of [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#id) parameter as a comma-separated list of -- at most 50 -- channel IDs, then he/she will obtain several such resources from the endpoint.)

The simplicity comes from the fact that any such channel resource can be cached locally (in its original JSON text form received from the endpoint, or, otherwise, in any other form that retains all properties of this resource). Then, upon invoking the endpoint for a current server-stored resource, a structural (simple yet not trivial) difference operation can be applied for to see whether that resource changed and for to determine the exact changes that took place.

**2. The `Playlists.list` endpoint**

In the case of `Playlists.list`, the things are precisely analogous to those at point 1 w.r.t. the `Channels.list` endpoint.

**3. The `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint**

Things get more complicated when needing to keep track of the changes occurred w.r.t. the items of any given playlist. The `PlaylistItems.list` endpoint comes to use is such situation, but, unfortunately, several issues arise in this context:

- Practically a playlist can grow to be huge (if only considering the uploads playlist of certain channels that have hundreds of thousands of entries).
- By design, there's [an upper 20000 limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880610/8327971) set for the number of items returned via `PlaylistItems.list` when queried for a given channel's uploads playlist.
- Due to the previous two bullets above, in cases, it's infeasible or even impossible to compute a set-theoretic difference between locally cached and remotely-stored list of items of a playlist. Thus, in the general case (i.e. when one is not considering the peculiarities of certain playlists), one cannot say with precision what are the items that *were removed from, were added to and remained in* the playlist.

The YouTube Data API provides no means to an user to determine which video items got deleted from a given playlist and when that happened. Yet that user may well determine which items were added to a playlist and when that happened by using the [`Activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) endpoint.

Thus an user keeping track of changes occurring to a playlist can only answer partially to the set-theoretic difference question which solves his/her problem ideally.

A caveat of using the `Activities.list` endpoint is the following: the endpoint returns a whole set of type of activities that take place w.r.t. a given channel (as specified by the [Activities resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource)). The `type` property enumerates them all:

> [**snippet.type**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.type) (string)
> The type of activity that the resource describes.
>
> Valid values for this property are: *channelItem*, *comment* (not currently returned), *favorite*, *like*, *playlistItem*, *promotedItem*, *recommendation*, *social*, *subscription*, *upload*, *bulletin* (deprecated).

Consequently, while monitoring `Activities.list`, the result sets obtained from the endpoint could well contain lots of noise when the API user is only interested in `playlistItem` activities.

Comment: Thanks for your input, stvar. Have to see if this will be a benefit for my application.

Comment: I myself am using a different strategy for monitoring playlist item updates ([already described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65275884/youtube-data-api-how-unique-is-playlistitem-id#comment115409712_65275884) that to you to a little extent). Should you deem that helpful, I'll gladly elaborate more. In any case, you could well be hacking GNU/Linux source code, since [my app](https://github.com/stvar/youtube-data) is free-software in its entirety.

Comment: There's also the possibility of employing [API push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications). But that's useful only when a channel does any of the following:  uploads a video, updates a video's title and updates a video's description. Never tried that myself; SO contains a few [entries related to that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56224370/8327971).